# Elasticsearch prefixing boolean fields to increase cardinality for query performance

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an Elasticsearch index of user's items, some item's fields are boolean, smth like this

```
{
  "user_id": "123",
  "yellow": true,
  "new": false,
}
```

Any query to this index comes with a user id, e.g. match (user_id=123 and yellow=true).
An ex-colleague that I no longer can talk to suggested the following

> Low-cardinality fields (e.g. booleans) are really bad in Elasticsearch. ES doesn't have efficient joins. A filter on this field will return a bitfield of every document that is unread, which is then intersected with the other filters.

It makes sense in theory. ES will index "yellow:true" to a long list of items of every user out there. So user 123's items will have to be intersected with this huge set to output a result. We ended up prefixing all booleans with user ids and matching by keyword.

```
{
  "user_id": "123",
  "yellow": "123_true",
  "new": "123_false",
}
```

I wonder if this is true or an overkill? I googled for an hour and couldn't find any source that would support this, so I'm skeptical.

Comment: Definitely overkill !! I don't know what sources your colleague went through but his statement doesn't really make any sense.